# Что за новый анти-вандальный бот, и почему он не локализован?

Tags: обсуждение, бот

Только что увидел на вопросе, который ТС вандализировал ([как увеличить array с помощью ref чтобы не потерять данные?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/969714)), вот такой комментарий:

> Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on Stack Overflow, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license for SO to distribute that content. By SO policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, please read more at How does deleting work? – iBot 11 минут назад

Вопросы:

- что это за новый бот (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/322268/ibot)?
- какие у него роли/полномочия?
- кто автор, это SE или частная инициатива?
- вероятно его надо локализовать.

Comment: И кстати - не думаю, что этот бот что то изменит. Как правило, такие участники(вандальщики) даже не обратят внимания на комментарий. Тут только редактирование. А для этого подойдет и SmokeDetector - который посылает подозрительные вопросы в чат. Его кстати тоже неплохо было локализовать.

Comment: @AntonSorokin после редактирования надо в любом случае оставлять комментарий. Если бот будет локализован - он будет полезным.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am the human owner behind iBot. I don't speak any Russian so I'll answer your questions in English. (I can read your questions and comments with the help of Google Translate.) Sorry about that.

1. It's my bot with modified code from [SmokeDetector](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector). At present, the only different behavior visible to the public is that it posts comments when someone vandalizes their posts. On English Stack Overflow, this happens quite frequently, and posting comments is what people usually do upon seeing one, so I automated this work.
2. It's no different from any other user except it's not operated directly by a human, but a computer program running 24/7. It has all the privileges that anyone with 101 reputation can have, but no more than that.
3. It's operated by me and is not connected with Stack Exchange or [Charcoal](https://charcoal-se.org/about) (the organization behind SmokeDetector, where I'm also a developer). I take all responsibility for all actions taken by iBot.

   On a side note, I am a full-time university student, so I'm not particularly active on Stack Exchange except on holidays (primarily January, February, July and August). Despite, I still check Stack Exchange regularly, so any notifications will likely be seen in less than a day.
4. Yes, please go here as suggested by Suvitruf → [Перевод для сообщения бота от iBug](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8965/15479). I will be happy to include your translation into my code.

   **Update**: I have taken the comment from the most upvoted answer from the above thread. I shortened it a bit so it fits into a 600-char comment. You should see it when the next vandalism happens.

Comment: Hi, happy to see you here. Thanks for clarification and translation plans :-)

Comment: But how did you earn association bonus? I don't see any questions, edits, or something another on your bot account. (Sorry for bringing up an old topic!)

Comment: @Peteird Couldn't remember that after so many years (and the bot is no longer running). I might have answered some easy homework questions on English SO to grab the initial 200 rep - some of which might have been deleted later.

Comment: @iBug Thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 4):

В профиле бота есть 1 контакт - [iBug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5958455/ibug) - пользователь SE. Это человек, который работал над SmokeDetector.

У него в профиле есть только гитхаб, где он состоит в сообществе [Charcoal-SE](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE)(разработчики SmokeDetector). У них есть почта, можно туда написать. НО: По какой то причине, SmokeDetector до сих пор не локализован. Поэтому, если это бот от Charcoal(а у них на гитхабе нет репозитория с iBot), могут возникнуть такие же проблемы с локализацией(если конечно SmokeDetector вообще пытались локализовать). Но так как SmokeDetector сидит в чате, а [iBot](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/322268/ibot) - на ruSO, то все таки стоит его локализовать, так как его будут видеть люди, которые не знают английский.

Также у бота в профиле есть [ссылка на чат Charcoal SE](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65945/charcoal-test), где можно узнать о локализации подробнее.

UPD: [Спросил про локализацию в чате.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49927952#49927952)

Comment: Не подскажите, насколько он легитимен? Т.е. это частная инициатива или официальная часть SE?

Comment: @Kromster частная.

Comment: @Kromster сейчас напишу им в чат, спрошу про локализацию.

Comment: @Kromster в чате [ответили](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49927974#49927974), что его разработчик iBug, и они ничего не знают/не могут сделать. Самого iBug`а давно не было в чате, он даже не пингуется с @, но ответ давал на SO вчера. Можно будет через день написать в комментариях к его ответу, ну а на крайний - можно забанить бота))

Answer (score 4):

Я связался с ним в чатике, он может для SOru перевод добавить. Предлагаю в отдельном треде выбрать лучший перевод: [Перевод для сообщения бота от iBug](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8965/15479).