# Перевод для сообщения бота от iBug

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, бот

По следам треда: [Что за новый анти-вандальный бот, и почему он не локализован?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8960/15479)

iBug может добавить перевод текста для SOru, если мы такой ему предоставим. Предлагайте свой вариант перевода:

> Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your
>   posts. By posting on Stack Overflow, you've granted a non-revocable
>   right, under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license for SO to distribute that
>   content. By SO policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to
>   know more about deleting a post, please read more at How does deleting
>   work?

Лучший отправлю ему ^_^

**P.S.** не обязательно переводить дословно. Это не официальный текст (:

**P.P.S.** длина сообщения должна быть не более 600 символов.

Comment: а описание в профиле будем править? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/u/322268

Comment: @mymedia можно попросить )

Comment: Hi Suvitruf. I think users need to be aware that whatever translation they give, it cannot exceed 600 characters. Can you help clarify that?

Comment: @iBug, hi, thanks. I've updated the question (:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Мой перевод (подглядывал в [перевод от Kromster](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8968/191745)):

> Пожалуйста, не создавайте лишнюю работу другим участникам, вандализируя собственные посты. При размещении сообщения на сайте «Stack Overflow на русском» вы даёте SO, в соответствии с лицензией [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82_%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%B8_Creative_Commons_Attribution-ShareAlike_3.0_Unported#%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4), неотзываемое право на распространение своего контента. В соответствии с политикой SO любые вандальные действия будут отменены. Если вы желаете узнать больше про удаление постов, пожалуйста, прочитайте ["Как работает удаление?"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2293).

Comment: *"неотзываемое согласие"* звучит несколько непривычно. Это общепринятый оборот? В остальном +1.

Comment: Насчёт общепринятости ничего не скажу, но несколько раз я этот оборот встречал, именно в контексте свободных лицензий.

Comment: @Kromster, мне кажется, должно быть "право", а не "согласие".

Comment: @Qwertiy в своем варианте так и перевел.

Comment: @Qwertiy согласен, "право" тут более уместно

Comment: @PavelMayorov как минимум «пост» надо заменить на «сообщение», потом запятые поправить можно будет.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ так-то да, но слово "сообщение" уж сильно напоминает "комментарий"... Где-нибудь можно увидеть как post переводился в других местах сайта?

Comment: @PavelMayorov https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=post

Comment: @αλεχολυτ а с запятыми прикола я не понял. Специально же каждое предложение вычитывал, консультируясь с Грамотой.ру... Я что-то пропустил?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ за ссылку спасибо. Как-то не обращал раньше на все эти переводы внимания, почему-то казалось что post повсеместно переводится как "пост" :-)

Comment: Немного поправил запятые, кмк, правильно. И некоторые соглашения по переводу учёл.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ зря вы запятые убрали. Хоть оба варианта и верны, но обстоятельный оборот в середине предложения, да ещё и объясняющий о чём говорится, обычно обособляется.

Comment: Слово «вандализируя» звучит немного не по-русски (и не похоже на переходный глагол). Может, просто «уничтожая»?

Comment: @VladD а что нем не русского? Слово "вандализм" в русском языке существует...

Comment: @PavelMayorov: «Вандализм» существует, а против «вандализировать» возмущается моё чувство языка: это слово мне кажется калькой с английского. (Ну и [gramota.ru тоже](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x) не в курсе.)

Comment: *вандализируя собственные посты*. Только ли **собственные** или нет ( [*...when someone vandalizes their posts..*](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8972/191745) ) ? В описании работы и тексте для перевода разные смысл. **вандализируя** - [а есть ли такое слово](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n90u6.png)  ?

Comment: @Alex чужие тоже нельзя вандализировать, но конкретно в переводимом сообщении говорится о собственных постах. Местоимение *their* тут относится к *someone*.

Comment: @VladD, Alex, в русском языке существует такая штука, как морфология и её правила. Которыми можно пользоваться для получения новых слов.

Comment: @PavelMayorov т.е. бот будет писать коммент только если Вы испортите свой пост ?

Comment: @Alex конкретно этот комментарий - да. При вандализации чужого сообщения нет ни малейшего смысла рассказывать про CC-BY-SA и право на распространение. Тут решается именно проблема авторов, которые считают, что их сообщения принадлежат  только им, и пытаются через вандализм "удалить" своё сообщение.

Comment: @PavelMayorov морфология тоже [не находит](http://www.morfologija.ru/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0/%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8F). Но даже если в каком-то словаре и есть слово *вандализировать*, "вандализируя"  как-то не звучит. Конечно, это только мое субъективное мнение.

Comment: @Alex при чем тут вообще словари? В русском языке разрешено получать новые слова из существующих.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Можно, конечно. Но вы ж не можете из слова «софизм» механически получить слово «софизировать»? Точно так же мою языковую интуицию возмущает слово «вандализировать». Вероятно, ваше чувство языка с «вандализировать» согласно, поэтому, как мне кажется, имеет смысл переспросить на тематическом ресурсе. Мы всё же не лингвисты тут.

Comment: @VladD *"Но вы ж не можете из слова «софизм» механически получить слово «софизировать»?"* - конечно же могу!

Comment: @PavelMayorov: „Но ты же не можешь на вопрос «почему?» ответить просто «гладиолус»? — Могу!“ (ц)

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Я к тому, что раз мы не сошлись во мнениях, уместно ли такое словообразование, имеет смысл выставить вопрос на суд профессионалов (желательно вместе с контекстом).

Comment: Отменен на отклонен поменять. Отменен как-то странно звучит в этом контексте...

Comment: @iluxa1810 "отклонён" в рамках SO скорее можно сказать про предложенную правку. А тут никто правку не предлагал, тут её взяли и сделали. Остаётся только откатывать.

Comment: Можно так и написать - "откачен", но тут уже мое чувство языка протестует...

Comment: Ещё вариант - *"любой вандализм откатят"*, но тут что-то не так со штилем.

Comment: Тогда предотвращен. "Отменить вандализм" как-то не так звучит., а "предотваратить вандализм" более лучше.

Comment: @iluxa1810 затруднительно предотвратить уже состоявшийся вандализм. Может, исправлен?

Comment: Может быть "В соответствии с политикой SO любые вандальные действия будут отменены". Просто, мне кажется, что нужно что-то добавить между "отменой" и "вандализмом", иначе как-то туго звучит.

Comment: @iluxa1810 мне нравится ваш вариант

Comment: Правда, "вандальные" тупо звучит и я бы заменил на "негативные" или "отрицательные".

Comment: @iluxa1810 нет, звучит не тупо. Негативное/отрицательное действие - это поставить минус сообщению. А заменить текст сообщения на "аааааааааааааааа" - это вандальное действие.

Comment: может "варварские"? Если верить вики, то это синоним к "вандализму". Вроде, нет такого слова как вандальный.

Comment: а не, есть https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9 .

Answer (score 4):

Черновой вариант (выделил сомнительные места с помощью полужирного начертания):

> Пожалуйста, не занимайтесь вандализмом сообщений, не создавайте другим людям лишнюю работу. Размещая сообщение на "Stack Overflow на русском", вы делаете это, соглашаясь с лицензией [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82_%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%B8_Creative_Commons_Attribution-ShareAlike_3.0_Unported#%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4), тем самым давая SO неотъемлимое право на его распространение. Согласно политике ruSO, любой вандализм будет **отменен**. Если вы хотите узнать больше о возможностях по удалению сообщений, пожалуйста обратитесь к справке - ["Как работает удаление?"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2293)

Comment: тут запятой не хватает после слова, **это**

Comment: может отменен заменить на *ликвидирован*?

Comment: 1 - спс, внес. 2 - сомневаюсь. Ликвидация это вроде как удаление, а тут именно *отмена, откат, восстановление оригинала* .. неверен как лучше.

Comment: Справочная страница была переведена, вот перевод - https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2293

Comment: *How does deleting work?* - вероятно стоит написать *Как работает удаление?*. И ссылка, которую выше написал Pavel Mayorov не помешает

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, нечего с вандалами сюсюкаться всякими «пожалуйста». Надо быть пожёстче. Да и давать ссылку на текст лицензии в Википедии, который так же можно отвандалить, крайне неразумно (вот только на официальном сайте СС я не нашёл перевода). К тому же я изменил текст, чтобы он стал понятнее для русскоговорящего читателя.

Вот черновой набросок, правки принимаются:

> Автор, не создавайте бессмысленной работы участникам сайта, вандализируя вопросы и ответы. Опубликовав на сайте свои материалы, вы неотчуждаемо передали Stack Overflow права на них в объёме, указанном в лицензии [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82_%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%B8_Creative_Commons_Attribution-ShareAlike_3.0_Unported#%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4) (см. [п. 6 пользовательского соглашения](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#licensing)), так что мы откатим этот акт вандализма. Если же вы хотите просто удалить свой вопрос/ответ, [сделайте именно это](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2294/208074).

Comment: Тогда уж *"Опубликовав ..., вы неотчуждаемо передали"*

Comment: Да, так действительно лучше (акт передачи уже произошёл, и мы просто напоминаем). Исправил.

Comment: И спасибо за более точный URL на TOC. Жаль только, что нет якорей на конкретные абзацы.

Answer (score -5):

Пожалуйста, не делайте больше работы для других людей, отбирая ваши посты. Размещая на StackOverflow, вы предоставили не подлежащее отзыву право в соответствии с лицензией CC BY-SA 3.0 для SO распространять этот контент. Таким образом, любой вандализм будет отменен. Если вы хотите узнать больше об удалении сообщения, пожалуйста, прочитайте больше о том, как работает удаление?

Comment: `отбирая ваши посты` - у кого отбирая? Формулировка непонятная.